# Issue with repeat break loop in R

Tags: r, loops, break, repeat

I am undertaking arima modelling and need to perform backward stepwise removal of variables by removing the lowest ranked (highest p_value) term (variable) and then re-running the modelling and outputs.

I have written 6 functions and use all of them in a function called `backward_stepwise`. Where the two inputs are x = a time series object and y = a data frame (same data as x which will have columns removed and then converted to a time series object).

If I step the function out and run each line separately it works as expected, however when ran within the function it does not.

I believe the issue lies where x is originally inputted as a time series object. Further down in the function x is redefined `x<-cond_select(x = y, y = remove_num_one)`

How do I go about redefining x as the current approach is not working?

```
backward_stepwise<-function(x, y){
 repeat{
  arima_result<-auto_arima(x)
  arima_pvals<-p_calc(arima_result)
  arima_outputs<-run_outputs(arima_result, arima_pvals)
  arima_ranked<-rank_pval(arima_outputs)
  remove_num_one<-remove_one(arima_ranked)
  x<-cond_select(x = y, y = remove_num_one)

  if(min(arima_ranked$rank, na.rm = TRUE) != 1){

  }

  break
 }

  return(arima_ranked)

}
```

Output is a df as follows:

```
term        coef        pval   rank
intercept   1813100.88  0.000  NA
Price.Diff  -70754.08   0.015  NA
School      19136.72    0.091  NA
Easter      -56811.50   0.469  1
Christmas   -53763.55   0.046  NA
High.Week   -436343.74  0.000  NA
Low.Week    187945.17   0.005  NA
```

However, the repeat loop should remove Easter and re-run model and outputs and break when min$rank != 1 therefore a rank column of all NAs.

Many thanks

Comment: Stepwise procedures are terrible

Comment: @Dason why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your `break` is misplaced. Try

```
if(min(arima_ranked$rank, na.rm = TRUE) != 1){
  break
}
```

And remove the `break` that is further down.

Altogether:

```
backward_stepwise<-function(x, y){
  repeat{
    arima_result<-auto_arima(x)
    arima_pvals<-p_calc(arima_result)
    arima_outputs<-run_outputs(arima_result, arima_pvals)
    arima_ranked<-rank_pval(arima_outputs)
    remove_num_one<-remove_one(arima_ranked)
    x<-cond_select(x = y, y = remove_num_one)

    if(min(arima_ranked$rank, na.rm = TRUE) != 1){
      break
    }
  }

  return(arima_ranked)

}
```

Comment: thankyou very much. One small error and throws everything out of whack!